# regex to stop at the first match instead of the last? using PHP

Tags: regex

If I have `a111Ta222T`

I wish to extract in PHP `a111T`

The point is to stop match at the **first** occurence of T, instead of at the last T.

How can I do this using regex?

---

*I don't wish to use*  `a[\S]+(?=a)`

*which can have the same result* `a111T`

Comment: Why you do   not wish to use `a[\S]+(?=a)` if it works?

Comment: @Jens: Probably because it won't work for longer instances.

Comment: The question is too broad as is - there are many different ways to extract the data. It can be as strict as `a\d+T` or as liberal as `[^T]+T`.

Comment: thanks for accept my edit I up voted you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use non greedy `+?`

```
/a.+?T/
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fF0wD6/1)

**Test**

```
preg_match('/a.+?T/', 'a111Ta222T', $matches);
echo $matches[0]
=> a111T
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^a\S+?T
```

You can simply do this.`+?` is non greedy and will stop at the first instance of `T`.You would also want to `^` anchor your string in order to stop at first `T`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex

```
[^T]+T
```

check this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iJ5zS5/1)

if you want your match to start with letter `a` you can use `a[^T]+T`